# php database update not working

Tags: php, mysql

Basically i want to update my database with values from an array that i converted from javascript to php
then when a button is pressed it updates the database
i have this code but it doesnt update to the database

```
var v = document.getElementsByName('mark[]');
var arr = new Array();
for(var a=0; a<v.length; a++){
arr[a]=inputs[a].value; 
}
var str;
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

    str+='&array_items[]='+arr[i];
}
document.location.href='./markandfeedback.php?'+str;
}




</script>";


for ($i=0; $i<count($_GET['array_items']); $i++){ 

    $arr[] = $_GET['array_items'][$i];
}




    if(isset($_POST['update'])){    

    $sql1="UPDATE `groupdatabase1` .`questions` SET `mark`= '".$arr[1]."',`studentID`= '4140001', `feedback` = 'meh' WHERE `questions`.`questionID`=1";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML? Is this a form? Do you want to use AJAX? IF not, then whay dont you just submit the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning your query to the variable named `$sql1`, but then using a different (probably uninitialized variable) named `$sql` in your call to `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 0):

Well youre not sending a `POST` request youre sending a `GET` so `$_POST['update']` will never exist. In addiiton to that im not sure why there is a `"` sfter the script tag... unless youre omitting code and thats actually written inside php theres no reason for it.

Typically you would use AJAX for this, otherwise you would use a form... even if you still run your JS and put the results in a set of hidden fields so there is no real form interface.